# ReactJS - wait for cookie to load before running function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, routes, http-redirect

I have a React App that straight away (on load), checks to see if there is a cookie, then if there is a cookie, it performs a function etc.

But the app will be loaded up from a Redirect

[image]

This is the code so far:

```
export class Landing extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        function onLoad(props) {

            const cookieValue = Cookies.get("cookieJWT");

            if(cookieValue){
               console.log(cookieJWT);
            } else { console.log('No cookie found!') }
        }

        onLoad();
   }
}
```

The problem is, the onLoad() function runs so quick before the cookie from redirect is ready, so  returns as not there!

I have tried to use componentDidMount(), but think I need to use async and await, but how do I do this so it waits for cookie to load/redirect to finish properly?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

yes this is what you need to do ,it's name callback.

btw I think it's better in react to use localStorage insted of cookie.

```
 // set
 try {
  yield localStorage.setItem("jwt","some value");
  } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
  }    

//get
 try {
   const jwt= yield localStorage.getItem(jwt); //some value
   const token= yield localStorage.getItem(token);//null
  } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
  }
```